# is the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ then  the sequence  $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing  or  strictly  decreasing ?

My attempts  : $\sqrt [n+1] e > 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ that  is  $e >(1 + \frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{n+1}$

so  $\{a_n\}$ is  strictly  increasing

Pliz  verified

Am i right  /wrong ?

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: What about taking the derivative ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust imnot getting

Comment: Did you try testing out your result? $a_1 = (1+1)^2 = 4 > 3.375 = (1+1/2)^3 = a_2$ So it isn't strictly increasing at the very least.

Comment: Your attempt shows that the sequence is bounded from above by $e$ but not that it is monotonically increasing or decreasing. (Since it also converges to $e$, it therefore cannot be decreasing.) To check whether it is increasing or decreasing, you could examine the difference $a_{n+1} - a_n$ (difficult) or the quotient $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ (more promising) or the difference of logarithms $\log a_{n+1} - \log a_n$ (even more promising). See where this takes you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=(x+1)\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)$$so that

$$f'(x)=\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\frac1x.$$

Clearly, the derivative is negative and the function decreasing.

Comment: thanks u @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that
$$\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}<\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
We consider the Quotient

$$\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}}=\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{n(n+2)}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right)^{n+1}$$
Using the inequality by Bernoulli we get
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right)^{n+1}>1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: thanks u @Dr sonnhard